# how to show specific version and install specific version of chart in helm 3 using command

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy flink using helm 3, and I want to see the flink version in helm, what command should I use to see the helm chart version in helm 3? I have read docs and searching from internet and tried:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm search -r "*flink*"
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -r
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm show all flink
Error: failed to download "flink" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm search -l flink
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'l' in -l
```

What should I do to check the version and install specific version of flink or other chart in helm 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`helm search` is for searching a keyword in charts and not for searching chart or versions.

You can use [helm hub](https://hub.helm.sh) to search for a chart which shows chart versions. Then use the command as below with `--version` to install chart with a specific version

```
helm repo add riskfocus https://riskfocus.github.io/helm-charts-public/
helm install riskfocus/flink --version 0.1.16
```

You could use [`helm search hub [keyword] [flags]`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_search_hub/) command as well instead of UI to search for chart and versions.

Comment: 0.1.16 is the flink 1.10, but I want to install flink 1.11. and thank you for your patient.@Arghya Sadhu

Comment: Check the application version..1.11 is new... helm release is not yet out for that version

Answer (score 2):

Try `helm search hub flink` :)

```
URL                                                     CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/ververica/ververica-...      4.2.0           2.2.0           Ververica Platform is the enterprise stream pro...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/riskfocus/flink              0.1.16          1.10.1          Chart for Apache Flink
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/flink-operator/flink...      0.1.1           1.0             A Helm chart for flink on Kubernetes operator
```